# Plotting data in matlab from csv file, with dates?

Tags: matlab, csv, plot

So my question is in two parts:

1. I am trying to graph data from CSV file in matlab: Here is what i have so far:

   ```
   filename = fopen('\fileDir.csv\', 'rt');
   FILE = textscan(filename, '%s %f %f', 'delimiter', ',' 'HeaderLines', 1);
   Date = FILE{1};
   Start = FILE{2};
   Stop = FILE{3};
   ```

   So I am trying to `plot(Date, Start)` in MATLAB. Clearly this wont work, since `Date` is a string. How should I approach changing the code?

   Date inside the `csv` file is in the format: `9/1/2014`, `10/12/2014`, `12/5/2014`, etc...(so there are no preceding zeros in month and day).
2. With this data I do some calculation. Lets assume my `csv` file has length 100. (`Date`, `Start`, `Stop` length is 100). I would create a new array dependent on variable `n`. `NEW_ARRAY` length would be 80, if `n` is 20, if `NEW_ARRAY` length is 85, `n` is 15. Then I would want to `plot(Date, NEW_ARRAY)`, but since they would be different lengths, I want `Date` to start at 16th (`n+1`) element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot dates in MATLAB by first converting them to numeric data with [`datenum`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html). Then you can use [`datetick`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) to display the tick labels as formatted dates.

So we could plot your data with

```
plot(datenum(Date), Start);
datetick('x', 20);
```

where `20` is a specific [`dateformat`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html#inputarg_dateFormat) identifier.

In order to display the dates on the graph using the Data Cursor we need to edit the [`datacursormode`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html) and add our own `'UpdateFcn'`. We can do this by writing a function as

```
function output_txt = datacursordate(~, event_obj)
    pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
    output_txt{1} = ['X: ' datestr(pos(1), 20)];
    output_txt{2} = ['Y: ' num2str(pos(2))];
end
```

and then applying this to the `datacursormode` with

```
h = figure;
plot(datenum(date), start)
datetick('x', 20)
dcm_obj = datacursormode(h);
set(dcm_obj, 'UpdateFcn', @datacursordate)
```

---

As for your second problem we can do this by indexing `Date` with `Date(n + 1:end)`. This will start using `Date` at the `(i + 1)`th element and continue all the way until the `end` of `Date`.

```
plot(datenum(Date(n + 1:end)), NEW_ARRAY);
datetick('x', 20);
```

Comment: This graphs fine. But when i select a point on the graph using data cursor, the y value is fine, but the x value doesnt have the date. How can i get the x value to be the date of the selected point