# MATLAB Time Vs Voltages Graph

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

Hi i am having a real time data of Time in cell array (6x1)

```
Time=
'03:01:00.000'
'03:01:10.000'  
'03:01:20.000'  
'03:01:30.000'  
'03:01:40.000'  
'03:01:50.000'
```

and voltages in double array (6x1)

```
Voltages=
231.098  
231.145 
231.032     
230.958   
230.981 
231.038
```

I am trying to draw a graph and have tried different approches...

**1-** Use plot function but as it accept only numeric values and i tried convert the cell into Numeric value.. by using
Time=cell2mat(Time) but then in return (6x12) number array
plot function requires matrix dimensions same so this method is not working

**2-** Second i tried to convert Time (6x1) cell array into char

Time=char(Time) again get 6x12 this time i also tried to use concatenates horizontal function
Time=horzcat (Time)
but even though i was successfully combine all the char and make a string but still my array size is 6x12

**3-** In third part i use time series function

time_ref = timeseries(Voltages,Time);
Now i can draw the graph but i am getting very unusual value of Date on x-axis..
there is one option in timeseries where i can adjust the starting date..

i even tried this one
time_ref.TimeInfo.StartDate = '05-Jan-2011'; to adjust the date value according to my date which i need but once i set this date my time value in graph is gone and showing some thing else value of time.. now i need you people help...

Please note that in real i have 360x1 cell array for Time and 360x1 double array for time but for simplicity i gave only 6x1 but these graphs are showing 360x1 values.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would like to mention that these two graphs are with 360x1 values of Time which is                                                                              '03:01:00.000'
'03:01:10.000' 
'03:01:20.000' 
'03:01:30.000' 
'03:01:40.000' 
'03:01:50.000'
.
.
.
'04:00:00.000' same way i used 360x1 values of voltages

Comment: Someone will edit to add the images but please indicate which image goes with which part of the question

Comment: I was going to answer this but it would result in me copying and pasting my answer from [Plotting data in matlab from csv file, with dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32803867/plotting-data-in-matlab-from-csv-file-with-dates).