# How to format dates on a plot and remove gap from time

Tags: matlab

I have the following plot created from this very simple script.

```
clear;

format long g

Ts  = ncread('EURUSD_1 hour_30_D_2015-11-03_02-52-36-PM.nc', 'TimeStamp');
Obs = ncread('EURUSD_1 hour_30_D_2015-11-03_02-52-36-PM.nc', 'Close');

plot(datenum(Ts), Obs);
datetick('x', 20);
```

However, I get this error:

```
>> netcdfExample
Error using datevecmx
Date number out of range.

Error in datevec (line 303)
   [y,mo,d] = datevecmx(t);

Error in dateTickPicker (line 85)
[y,m,d] = datevec(x);

Error in datetick>bestscale (line 292)
[labels,format] = dateTickPicker(axh,[xmin,xmax],dateform,dateChoice,axVal);

Error in datetick (line 251)
        ticks = bestscale(axh,ax,vmin,vmax,dateform,dateChoice);

Error in netcdfExample (line 9)
datetick('x', 20);

>>
```

When I just try something simple like this

```
>> formatOut = 'mmmm-dd-yyyy';
>>  str = datestr(6.35821236e+17,formatOut,'local')
```

I get this error. I wonder if these encoded date numbers are wrong?

```
Error using dateformverify (line 28)
DATESTR failed converting date number to date vector.

Error in datestr (line 194)
S = dateformverify(dtnumber, dateformstr, islocal);

Caused by:
    Error using datevecmx
    Date number out of range.
```

The datetimes/close look like this (in the .csv vesion)

```
9/22/2015 16:15 1.11255
9/22/2015 17:00 1.11305
9/22/2015 18:00 1.112
9/22/2015 19:00 1.1107
9/22/2015 20:00 1.1123
```

The date is from hourly intra-day data (netcdf format) that I read from a file into Matlab :[image: EURUSD]

As you can see, the x-axis are numbers in 10^17 format instead of System.DateTime from C#. Also, please note that since the markets close and reopen, there is a line joining the plot between when the market closes, and reopens.

How do I:

1. Get rid of the date gap. I want the data to be next to its neighbor.
2. Make the x-axis tick marks be something resembling a date/time?
3. The y axis data has five decimal places of precision. How do I ask the plot to show more precision on the y-axis tick marks?

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32808701/1552737) to [Plotting data in matlab from csv file, with dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32803867/plotting-data-in-matlab-from-csv-file-with-dates) should help. Specifically the use of [`datetick`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html).

Comment: Thanks, see my updated post.

Comment: Doesn't help. See updated post.

Comment: See [`datenum`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) and its second parameter too (in the documentation). I'm not going to write the code for you.

Comment: I don't see how datenum helps. The data in Ts is already "datenum" format. I am trying to go the other direction - from number to date/time.

Comment: I tried instead to use datestr as in the edited post, and that gives an illuminating error.

Comment: Pay attention to the [date format identifier](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html#inputarg_dateFormat) you use with `datetick`. Currently, you have `20` which corresponds to `'dd/mm/yy'` which is **not at all** what your data is.

Comment: You can change the precision on the tick labels like this `ax = gca; set(ax,'YTickLabel',sprintf('%5.3f\n',get(ax,'YTick')));` - **however**, now your y-tick labels are strings and will no longer automatically update with your data. Proceed with caution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of figured out a workaround. In the C# program, instead of using a Datetime, I convert the Datetime to a double. Then this program works fine

```
Ts  = ncread('EURUSD_1 hour_30_D_2015-11-03_06-41-44-PM.nc', 'TimeStamp');
Obs = ncread('EURUSD_1 hour_30_D_2015-11-03_06-41-44-PM.nc', 'Close');

plot(Ts, Obs);
datetick('x', 'mm-dd-yy HHPM');
```

I still don't know how to add precision to the y axis, and how to remove the gaps in time on the x-axis. It is interesting because if I just say

```
plot(Obs)
```

The plot looks correct on the y-axis but the x-axis is numbers. If I add

```
plot(Ts, Obs)
datetick('x', 'mm-dd-yy HHPM');
```

Then the x-axis is correctly "indexed" by date/time, but I suspect that Matlab is honoring the gaps in time so the plot looks "jumpy" and disconnected.